# HAVING STATEMENT error SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle

I have updated this question sicne I have made progress, my `HAVING` statement is still not working correctly. I am getting a `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`..

I believe its my `HAVING` clause. Any Ideas?

**RECAP**:

I am trying to capture progress of customers who did not have purchasing activity between 2013-2015 and track their buying activity from Oct-2015 forward to track salesman activity..

```
SELECT INV.COMPANY
     , INV.CUSTOMER_ID
     , INV.ADDRESS_ID
     , INV.NAME
     , INV.ADDRESS1
     , INV.ADDRESS2
     , INV.CITY
     , INV.STATE
     , INV.ZIP_CODE
     , INV.COUNTRY
     , CICM.CLIENT_VALUE as contact_type
     , CICM.VALUE
     , CICM.DESCRIPTION
     , INV.REGION_CODE
     , INV.SITE
     , LD.LSTINVDATE
     , CASE WHEN TO_DATE(INV.INVDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Oct-13') AND TO_DATE('30-Sep-15') THEN SUM(INV.SALES) ELSE 0 END AS TWO_YEARS
     , CASE WHEN TO_DATE(INV.INVDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Oct-15') AND SYSDATE THEN SUM(INV.SALES) ELSE 0 END AS PROGRESS
     , SUM(INV.SALES) AS SLSAMNT

FROM IFSINFO.HB_INVOICING_ALL INV 
LEFT JOIN IFSINFO.HB_LAST_INVOICE_DATE LD 
    ON (INV.COMPANY = LD.COMPANY) 
    AND (INV.CUSTOMER_ID = LD.IDENTITY)
LEFT JOIN IFSAPP.CUSTOMER_INFO_COMM_METHOD CICM
    ON (INV.ADDRESS_ID = CICM.ADDRESS_ID)
    AND (INV.CUSTOMER_ID = CICM.CUSTOMER_ID)
WHERE INV.CUST_GRP = '4'
AND INV.COMPANY = '20'
HAVING SUM(INV.INVDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Oct-13') AND TO_DATE('30-Sep-15') = 0
--HAVING MAX(LD.LSTINVDATE) < (SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' YEAR)     
GROUP BY INV.COMPANY
       , INV.CUSTOMER_ID
       , INV.ADDRESS_ID
       , INV.NAME
       , INV.ADDRESS1
       , INV.ADDRESS2
       , INV.CITY
       , INV.STATE
       , INV.ZIP_CODE
       , INV.COUNTRY
       , CICM.CLIENT_VALUE
       , CICM.VALUE
       , CICM.DESCRIPTION
       , INV.REGION_CODE
       , INV.SITE
       , LD.LSTINVDATE  
       , INV.INVDATE
```

Comment: Do you have access to the data tracking customer marketing? Create a list of CustIDs with activty 2+ years and join your DirectMailing CustID to your sales table. Instant list of prior customers who have had direct marketing and any activity since whatever date.

Comment: @Dave, we currently do not. I am editing the question (I have made more progress) to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause is the cause of the error as it not syntactically correct. You have (added parentheses to show how it is parsed):

```
HAVING (SUM(..) BETWEEN x AND y) = 0
```

and the expression inside the parentheses returns a boolean result.

Additionally, the `SUM(INV.INVDATE)` doesn't make much sense. What result should one expect if we add dates?

And as @mustaccio correctly noticed, the `HAVING` clause goes **after** `GROUP BY`, not before.

---

It seems you want something like this in the `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TO_DATE(INV.INVDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Oct-13') 
                                              AND TO_DATE('30-Sep-15') 
           THEN INV.SALES ELSE 0 
           END) = 0
```

which I would prefer rewritten as:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN INV.INVDATE >= DATE '2013-10-01' 
                 AND INV.INVDATE < DATE '2015-10-01' 
             THEN INV.SALES ELSE 0 
           END) = 0
```

The `INV.INVDATE` should be removed from the `GROUP BY` clause as well and the `TWO_YEARS` and `PROGRESS` expressions should also be corrected as the  `SUM(...)` expression suggested `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN x ELSE y END)` instead of `CASE WHEN ... THEN SUM(x) ELSE y END`.

Comment: Good point! I am having `HAVING  CASE WHEN TO_DATE(INV.INVDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Oct-13') AND TO_DATE('30-Sep-15') THEN SUM(INV.SALES) ELSE 0 END < 1` run right now to see the results but I think your method is the clean way to approach this issue. Thank you for your reply and I will be testing it as soon as the query is done running! Thanks @ypercube for that info!

Comment: I think the bigger problem is that `HAVING` precedes `GROUP BY`...

Comment: @mustaccio thnx. I somehow missed that!

Comment: Good pointout @mustaccio Thank you for that!